# How to create a Toolbar in Opencv 2.4.9 with Qt

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I'm trying to follow [this exemple](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/qt_new_functions.html) but I'm stuck where the documentation don't show how to actually create the toolbar they're showing ...

(I'm working on Visual Studio 2013 with OpenCV 2.4.9 on a 64bit based aplication)

Am I missing something ?

EDIT : Here's a picture of the Toolbar(left), next to a Trackbar.
Please, if there is still confusion, tell me before downvoting so I can explain more.
[image: <- Toolbar | Trackbar ->]

Comment: Uh; yes they do. 'cvCreateTrackbar( "track2", NULL, &value2, 255, NULL);'

Comment: Uh; I'm sorry I thought I wrote 'Toolbar' and not 'Trackbar' ... Oh Wait !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can't create a toolbar.** The toolbar is created automatically by the OpenCV highgui module in every "NamedWindow" if OpenCV is compiled with Qt support. If you can't see this toolbars you should re-build OpenCV **with Qt support**. To do so, build OpenCV from source (by using CMAKE) and make sure the option WITH_QT is set.

If you build OpenCV with CMAKE GUI you can find this option in the configuration menu:

[image]

One thing you should have in mind is that OpenCV won't allow you to modify the toolbars as it does with the TrackBar or the NamedWindow.

Comment: Ok thanks, but if OpenCV won't allow the modification of the Toolbar, how can I create a custom one ?

Comment: As I said in my answer, **you can't** :S (not with OpenCV). I'd recommend you to learn Qt  for that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and now solved it after 2 days :D
I'm using OSX 10.9 with opencv 2.4.9 installed with brew and Qt Creator.
The Problem is the installation in brew. To see the toolbar you have to install -- with qt.

write in terminal (with brew) to install opencv (uninstall if opencv is already installed)

> brew install opencv --with-qt

Now you can use the toolbar in Xcode or
in QT Creator, create for instants QT widget App and add in the *.pro file:

> QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++
>
> QMAKE_MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 10.9
>
> LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib
>
> LIBS += \
>     -lopencv_calib3d \
>    -lopencv_contrib \
>   -lopencv_core \
>     -lopencv_flann \
>    -lopencv_gpu \
>    -lopencv_highgui \
>    -lopencv_imgproc \
>    -lopencv_legacy \
>   -lopencv_ml \
>   -lopencv_objdetect \
>       -lopencv_ocl \
>       -lopencv_photo \
>       -lopencv_stitching \
>       -lopencv_superres \
>       -lopencv_ts \
>       -lopencv_video \
>       -lopencv_videostab
>       -lopencv_nonfree
>
> INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/opencv \
>                      /usr/include/opencv \
>                   /usr/local/include
>
> DEPENDPATH += /usr/local/include/opencv/include